# Ensure Background Worker is Alive and Working

Tags: ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

Is there any way in ruby to determine if a background worker is running?

For instance, i have a server that works a queue in delayed job and i would like to ensure 4 workers are on it and spin up a new worker process if one has either stalled or quit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line, `crontab -l`gives a list of all currently running jobs.

From the Rails console, `Delayed::Job.all` will give you a list of all currently running jobs.

Delayed Job also has a list of lifecycle methods which you can access:

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/collectiveidea/delayed_job/Delayed/Lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

the usual way to do that is to use an external watchdog process. you can use [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) or [God](http://godrb.com)